# Discord.py Insert Values into Database using mysql-connector

Tags: python, sql, discord.py, mysql-connector

I am trying to insert values into a database through user input. The following code works without user input:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO DiscordData (UserID, Code) VALUES (%s, %s)"
val = ("1234", "foobar")
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
mydb.commit()
print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

However data isn't inserted when i pass the code into a command handler for user input:

```
@bot.command()
async def foo(message, arg):
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        await message.send(arg)
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        sql = "INSERT INTO DiscordData (UserID, Code) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        val = ("123", arg)
        await mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        await mydb.commit()
        print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

Comment: What database library are you using? If it isn't explicitly async, then `await mycursor.execute` doesn't make sense and will cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with mysql and discord bots for a few of my projects so I can give some insight to you here.

Firstly, you shouldn't need to use await on the `mycursor.execute` or `mydb.commit()` calls.

Secondly, the way I did my code was a bit different, take this for what it's worth but I know that it should work.  I had an SQLCmds.py file, which is imported into the main discord bot python file.  Inside the SQLCmds.py is all the necessary functions for placing new information into the MySQL Database.  So instead of calling SQL functions inside of the discord bot's code, you're calling a function similar to your top code and passing in whatever information the bot has.

So for example, here's a banned word check:

```
def checkBannedWord(banned_word):
    mycursor.execute("SELECT filtered_to FROM banned_word_table WHERE banned_word = '"+str(banned_word).lower()+"'")
    result = mycursor.fetchall()
    if result != []:
        return result[0][0]
    else:
        return False
```

In your discord bot's code, you'd be able to `checkBannedWord(banned_word)` and call this SQL function. It would make the whole process much more straightforward for you.